# Enviar mensagens em site na web(messenger online)

Tags: php, html, css, web-service, aplicação-web

Olá, quero criar um site de mensagens na internet(SMS messenger), tenho algumas duvidas:

- Quais linguagens deverei utilizar (notavelmente utilizarei HTML, CSS, JS)
- Precisarei utilizar banco de dados?
- Como fazer a troca de mensagens instantaneamente, não precisando recarregar a página.

Espero que fui claro, e aguardo o retorno...

Comment: Vc já tem plano de envio de SMS via web?

Comment: Não, (oq ser isso)?

Comment: Mas não quero enviar SMS no site (Isto é só o nome). Na realidade quero que ele funcione como se fosse um messenger online, onde os usuários cadastrados trocam mensagens entre si(como no messenger)

Comment: Achei que era SMS. Basicamente terá que usar Ajax, PHP (ou outro backend) e um banco de dados para guardar as mensagens (ex. MySQL)..

Comment: Valeu pelos esclarecimentos! mas será que com somente isso, as mensagens serão enviadas/recebidas instantaneamente, não sendo necessário o recarregamento(reload) da página?

Comment: Basicamente é isso. O JS pode verificar de tempo em tempo se há uma mensagem nova e mostrar para o destinatário via Ajax.

Comment: Então quer dizer que devo usar o "setInterval(checkarDados(),1000)" onde a função chekarDados() irá importar as mensagens do banco de dados, de tempos em tempos?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Tem que ver se o servidor aguenta uma requisição a cada segundo, ainda mais se tiver dezenas de usuários usando o sistema ao mesmo tempo. Seria `setInterval(checkarDados,1000)` (sem os parênteses da função).

Comment: Muito obrigado, está me ajudando muito! mas para fazer a importação deverei usar  a API XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Sim, o Ajax usa o XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Show de bola! muito obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vai ter que utilizar banco de dados e também php tive um projeto de chat que ele não atualizava a pagina mais no caso

Vai ser utilizado Php e MYSQL

Comment: Poderia descrever como basicamente funcionava esse Chat?

Comment: Ele precisa de um acesso ao moderador esse era o chat que eu tinha

Para controlar os clientes do chat era um chat aberto mais é so fazer um hub cada cliente que clicar no chat de atendimento ele vai enviar pra uma sala de espera até o moderador estiver disponivel e tem a opção tive o aplicativo da uber que tu desabilita pra não ser localizado ou até mesmo no site

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar firebase, https://firebase.google.com .
Embora, seja bom você aprender backend, você pode usá-lo para um backend completo.

Comment: Valeu pela recomendação, mas prefiro desenvolver na prática, do zero.